# Bypassing PHP XML errors when offline

Tags: php, xml, offline

I have local php website that has some online and some offline components.  It pulls xml data from various websites normally.  When offline, the page will not render due to various errors.

I use `$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);` to retrieve xml data.  When offline I usually get errors telling me that the target url doesn't exist and that certain nodes in the xml file cannot be retrieved.

How do I bypass these errors so that the rest of the page can be loaded when offline?

Comment: what do you mean offline?

Comment: I mean when not connected to the internet.  So a local webpage will give extra information when online and less info when offline.

Comment: wrap the load in a conditional that checks if you are "online" `if(online){$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);}`

Comment: What is the best way to check if online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

```
$var = @simplexml_load_file($url);
if(!$var){
    echo "error";
}
else{
    execute code...
}
```

Now when I'm offline, the script will leave an error message if it cannot connect and continue processing the page.  Before, it would reach an error and stop loading the rest of the page.